# Is there a way to detect the current SDK being used in a .targets MSBuild file?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

In .NET, you can specify which [.NET project SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview) you would like to use by specifying the `Sdk` attribute on the top-level `Project` element:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Web.Sdk">
```

I am writing a NuGet package and attempting to find an MSBuild property or item that saves off which SDK is being used. I am not having any luck in the official documentation nor when examining a build in the [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) in finding one.

Is there an idiomatic way to identify which Sdk has been selected for a project in an MSBuild .targets file?

I would have expected a property like

```
$(MSBuildProjectSdkName) // "Microsoft.NET.Web.Sdk"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest I've found using Rider IDE's Project Properties window:
[image: Rider IDE's Project Properties window]

This is in a project using the `Microsoft.NET.Web.Sdk`.
So it seems there are 3 SDK related properties set in a Web SDK project:

```
UsingMicrosoftNETSdk
UsingMicrosoftNETSdkRazor
UsingMicrosoftNETSdkWeb
```

I guess you can determine if the Web SDK is used with `Condition=" '$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdkWeb)' == 'true' "`